# Is the number of rows always 1 in each band in the Spark implementation of MinHashLSH

Tags: apache-spark, locality-sensitive-hash, minhash

I'm trying to understand the MinHash LSH implementation in Spark, `org.apache.spark.ml.feature.MinHashLSH`.

These two files seem the most relevant: [MinHashLSH.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fb2e3af4b5d92398d57e61b766466cc7efd9d7cb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/MinHashLSH.scala) and [LSH.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fb2e3af4b5d92398d57e61b766466cc7efd9d7cb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/LSH.scala).

To use MinHashLSH, the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/MinHashLSH.html) says it needs a `numHashTables` parameter, which is the

> Param for the number of hash tables used in LSH OR-amplification.

My understanding is that the [hashFunction](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fb2e3af4b5d92398d57e61b766466cc7efd9d7cb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/MinHashLSH.scala#L60-L69) method calculates the MinHash signature for each input instance (e.g. a collection of singles/tokens that represent a document), e.g.

```
data = [
    (0, Vectors.sparse(6, [0, 1, 2], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0])),
    (1, Vectors.sparse(6, [2, 3, 4], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0])),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "features"])

mh = MinHashLSH(inputCol='features', outputCol='hashes', numHashTables=5)
mh_model = mh.fit(df)
mh_model.transform(df).show(truncate=False)
```

outputs:

```
+---+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |features                 |hashes                                                                           |
+---+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0  |(6,[0,1,2],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|[[3.84540858E8], [5.873031E8], [6.9646868E8], [3.95377821E8], [1.050129459E9]]   |
|1  |(6,[2,3,4],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|[[3.19950681E8], [1.87323383E8], [1.237542508E9], [6.11223988E8], [2.07958525E8]]|
+---+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So `numHashTables` is the number of hash functions used/the length of the MinHash signature per input instance.

But I haven't seen anything related to the banding technique as introduced the chapter 3 of the book [Mining of Massive Datasets](http://www.mmds.org/) in the code yet. The banding technique basically partitions all the MinHash values of each instance into `b` bands with `r` rows in each band, so the product of `r` and `b` should be equal to the number of hash functions used. The tuning of `b` and `r` has important implications in the inclusion of false positives or false negatives when calculating candidate pairs.

From the way I see how the [sameBucket](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fb2e3af4b5d92398d57e61b766466cc7efd9d7cb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/LSH.scala#L126-L127) in [`approxNearestNeighbors`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fb2e3af4b5d92398d57e61b766466cc7efd9d7cb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/LSH.scala#L110) and [two-dataset join](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fb2e3af4b5d92398d57e61b766466cc7efd9d7cb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/LSH.scala#L288-L289) in [`approxSimilarityJoin`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fb2e3af4b5d92398d57e61b766466cc7efd9d7cb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/LSH.scala#L267) are implemented, it looks the number of rows is always assumed to be one, then the number of bands is equal to the number of hash functions, i.e. `numHashTables`, which is also consistent with the description that `numHashTables` is used in LSH OR-amplification.

However, if `r` is always one, assume `numHashTables=10`, we could be computing the Jarccard distance (aka. `keyDistance` in `MinHashLSH`) for many more pairs (false positives, related code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fb2e3af4b5d92398d57e61b766466cc7efd9d7cb/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/LSH.scala#L288-L295)) than we need to based on the equation

`Pr = 1 - (1 - s^r)^b`

where `Pr` is the probablity of a pair with Jaccard similarity (NOT distance) of `s` hashed to the same bucket.

So I'd like to confirm if my understanding is correct: the number of rows is assumed to be always 1 in the implementation of `org.apache.spark.ml.feature.MinHashLSH`, and the `numHashTables` is equal to both the number of hash functions used for calculating MinHash signature and the number of bands/hash tables used in locality sensitivity hash.

Answer (score 1):

I see on https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features#feature-transformation

> The type of outputCol is Seq[Vector] where the dimension of the array equals numHashTables, and the dimensions of the vectors are currently set to 1. In future releases, we will implement AND-amplification so that users can specify the dimensions of these vectors.

so it looks indeed the number of rows (used for AND-amplification) in each band is set to 1.